# How to open .sch files?

Tags: schematics, cad, orcad

I have what should be a schematic file from a vendor, its suffix is .sch.  I tried opening it with Eagle CAD but it wouldn't open.  I then looked at the file with a text editor and there seem to be some references to Orcad.

Does anyone know if .sch files are Orcad files, and if so where to get a free viewer program from?

Comment: ".sch" is the normal Eagle suffix for schematic file names, but also for other programs.  Keep in mind that the Eagle file formats are completely different from version 5 to version 6.  Version 5 are binary and version 6 XML based.  If Eagle 5 failed to open the file, it could still be a Eagle 6 file.

Comment: SCH is often used, I believe Protel(Altium) used it, Eagle, and some other open source editors as well. I am afraid it's hard to tell what it is, other than trying all the schematic tools out there (or understanding your source better!)

Comment: @OlinLathrop That sounds horrible! I would have imagined that they would have changed the suffix when they changed the format of the file.

Comment: I would try opening with a text editor first to see if possibly the data is human readable and they signed it. More reasonably, as the person whom gave you the schematic!

Comment: Altium (Formerly Protel) now uses .SchDoc for it's schematic postfix.

Comment: Personally, I want to track down every programmer/engineer who decided to use a generic file postfix for their program's files, and kick them in the head. Is it so hard to put your program name in the postfix? Something like .EglSch or .AltSch would be sooooo much more sensible.

Comment: @Kellenjb: Now that you mention it, I don't know what the schematic file name suffix is in Eagle 6.  I was just assuming they would keep it the same, but I hadn't really thought about it.  Version 6 is still way too buggy for real use, so I haven't tried to play with it, nor do I plan to for a year or two at least.

Comment: Can you post the file? Or even the first 100 bytes of the file?

Comment: Anyway, looking at what Olin said, it's likely that is Eagle 6 more than 5, because XML is readable text while binary is not.

Comment: This is now at the point of looking at answers and comments of people both saying that is not enough information on its own and a the option range is very large. How about give us a link from where you got the file or more information. I would suggest as one answer did, contact the vendor. This could easily be used as to narrow of a situation as we could generate a new question for every single vendor site that has schematics and have completely different advice.

Comment: There are many formats that use the .sch extension.  Even some created by a company's software can't be opened by later software from the same company.  I wrote a script to make it easier to open them in Windows: https://gist.github.com/endolith/1119561

Answer (score 6):

Orcad, PADS and Protel all used .sch at one point and there is no standard implied with the file type.  Orcad now uses .DSN.  Check with the vendor.  Most commercial products offer a free reader (aka viewer) or a free Lite version that limits modification but not the open, so users can view files.

Orcad makes a [free viewer](http://www.cadence.com/products/pcb/Pages/downloads.aspx).  As a sidebar I also like [ViewMate](http://www.pentalogix.com/viewmate.php) for Gerber viewing:

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file with gEDA, a open suite for electronic design

Comment: Not necessarily. The same postfix doesn't constitute a standard.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the vendor you got it from.

Answer (score 1):

PSpice "Schematic" (The generic version of OrCAD Capture) files have that extension. You can get the demo/student version [here](http://www.lcsee.wvu.edu/~gsbyun/ee251/ps9_1.zip).